# How do I restart a batch file in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, server, scripting

Here is what I have tried:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -eq "C:\path\stream1.bat"} | Stop-Process -Force

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c `"C:\path\stream1.bat`""
```

The `Start-Process` command works perfectly, however the `Stop-Process` command does nothing.

Comment: Regardless that you have answers already, and based on the fact you've already asked questions which have mentioned this batch file, I'd advise that you see if you can capture the ProcessId of the cmd.exe instance when you invoke it, (passing the batch file to it as an argument). It would make more sense than searching through CommandLine properties of each running cmd.exe instance, (especially as you're running multiple in parallel), to pair the ProcessId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with your current code is that [`.Path` (in reality this property is `.MainModule.FileName`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename?view=net-8.0#system-diagnostics-processmodule-filename) will be the path to `cmd.exe` not the `.bat` file itself. What you can do in this case is query `Win32_Process` and filter by the [`CommandLine` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process#properties) where it contains the path of your `.bat`. This solves one of the problems.

The next problem will be to find all sub processes that your `.bat` file could've started, these need to be terminated first before terminating `cmd.exe` itself. For this, again, you can query `Win32_Process` to find all processes having the `ParentProcessId` equal to the process id of your `cmd.exe` process.

```bash
$bat = 'C:\path\stream1.bat'

# WQL requires escaping of `\`
$cmdline = $bat.Replace('\', '\\')

$getCimInstanceSplat = @{
    Filter    = "Name = 'cmd.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%$cmdline%'"
    ClassName = 'Win32_Process'
}
# Find the cmd process containing the path of the `.bat` file
$proc = Get-CimInstance @getCimInstanceSplat

$getCimInstanceSplat = @{
    Filter    = "ParentProcessId = '$($proc.ProcessId)'"
    ClassName = 'Win32_Process'
}
# Find all processes started by that bat file
Get-CimInstance @getCimInstanceSplat |
    # and terminate all of them
    Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Terminate

# In case the parent process didn't terminate after that
# attempt to terminate it as well
$proc | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Terminate -EA 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78235353/45375) with a [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution:

```bash
Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore cmd | 
  Where CommandLine -match ('\b{0}\b' -f [regex]::Escape('C:\path\stream1.bat')) | 
  ForEach Kill $true
```

- In PowerShell 7, the objects output by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) have a `.CommandLine` property, which reflects the batch-file path (typically implicitly) passed to `cmd.exe` for execution of a batch file.
- Any matching process(es), along with their child processes, are then forcefully terminated via the [`.Kill()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill) method, with a `$true` argument passed to the `entireProcessTree` parameter, using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (one of whose built-in aliases is `ForEach`)  with [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax).

  - Note that, as of PowerShell 7.4.x, use of [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) is *not* an option, because it only forcefully terminates the target process *alone*, not also its descendants (process tree).
    [GitHub issue #15075](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15075) is a green-lit proposal to add a `-Recurse` / `-IncludeChildProcess` switch to `Stop-Process` to overcome this limitation.